# .Xresources font names

Tags: x11, fonts, x-resources

Many references describing the manipulation of bitmap font face and size for `xterm` via the `~/.Xresources` config file suggest the use of an entry like `XTerm.VT100.font: -*-fixed-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*-*`. I have wondered what is the purpose of the `-*` characters and whether there is any logic to their placement and number. All the references I have consulted use these characters in their examples for modifying the font (although the total length of the `-*` string is somewhat variable), but none explain the purpose or significance of these characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are designations for traditional, server-rendered X11 fonts. The name format is called [X logical font description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description) (XLFD). There is an introductory description in the [X man page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man7/X.7.html#sect8).

An XLFD contains 14 fields, each prefixed by a dash. The position of the field determines its meaning: foundry, family, weight, etc. A field can contain the value `*` to allow the server to pick any. For example:

- `-*-fixed-*-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` means any font whose family name is `fixed` and whose pixel size (height as a number of pixels on the screen) is 100 (which is huge).
- `-*-fixed-*-*-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*` means any font whose family name is `fixed` and whose point size (height in units of 0.1 points, where points are defined by the resolution in the next two fields) is 100 points (which is tiny).
- `-*-fixed-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*-*` doesn't match any font because it sets the style (which is something like `sans` or `condensed` — usually empty) to `100`. With missing fields, the last `*` matches multiple fields.

You can run [`xfontsel`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xfontsel.1.html) to browse the available fonts on your system. For bitmap fonts, xfontsel lists all available sizes. For vector fonts, you can pick any size.

Many applications support client-rendered fonts nowadays, which allows for nice features such as antialiasing. These use [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) to look up fonts, with completely different naming conventions.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks for the examples as well as for pointing me to the XLFD for the full specifications. I wasn't aware of `xfontsel`, but find it to be a rather helpful tool for viewing the effect of varying parameters. Your answer also explains why changing the number in the font designation in my question wasn't changing the font size: the number was in the `adstyl` column rather than the `pxlsz` column.